# EntityManager.createQuery().executeUpdate not updating the database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I am trying to update the Student class(`student_class`) column based on the `studentid`.
I am using `EntityManager` with Criteria to update the records. 
The code is compiling successfully, but records are not getting updated in the database.

**StudentEntity:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
Class StudentEntity{
 @Id
 @Column(name = "student_id")
 private long studentId;

 @Column(name = "student_name")
 private String studentName;

 @Column(name = "student_class")
 private String studentClass;
}
```

**Logic to update Student class column**

```
@Repository
pubilc class StudentRepository {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public void update(List < StidentEntity > studentList) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaUpdate < StudentEntity > criteriaUpdate = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(StudentEntity.class);
    Root < StudentEntity > root = creiteriaUpdate.from(StudentEntity.class);

    studentList.forEach(request - > {
            List < Predicate > predicates = buildWhereClase(cb, root, request);
            criteriaUpdate.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
            formUpdateQuery(criteriaUpdate, root, request);
            int res = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaUpdate).executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Update status: " + res);
        }
    }

    private List < Predicate > buildWhereClasue(CruteriaBuilder builder, Root < StudentEntity > root, StudentEntity request) {
        List < Predicate > predicates = new ArrayList < > ();
        predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("studentId"), request.getStudentId()));

        return predicates;
    }


    private void formUpdateQuery(CriteriaUpdate < StudentEntity > criteria, Root < StudentEntity > root, StudentEntity request) {
        criteria.set(root.get("studentClass", request.getStudentClass()));
    }
}
```

PleaseHiber help.

Comment: Depending on your configuration of the entity manager, I think you are missing a commit. Use em.getTransaction().commit().

Comment: Marcinek- I am using @Transactional annotation. That will take care of the transaction lifecycle.

Comment: Hence it does not update your entities in the database. Thus there is missing something. I'm not quite familiar with the CriteriaBuilder and using the EM on my own. Please make sure that @Transactional and EM are working fine together.

Comment: You use PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager from one galaxy, and Transactional uses an entityManager from another galaxy. You can use https://github.com/KonopkoMikhail/TransactionMonitor to make sure of this.

Comment: can you enable hibernate show-sql and check if the query is really being executed ?

Comment: Shawrup- Yes, show-sql is enabled and I don't see any update query.